# auto-py-to-exe .py file works but .exe pops a bunch of errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, error-handling, db2

I have a Python script that I would like to convert to exe. The conversion actually gives me a .exe file, but when I run it, this error pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TicketingIngenieria.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 546, in exec_module
  File "ibm_db", line 7, in <module>
  File "os.py", line 1111, in add_dll_directory
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] System cannot find the specified route: 'C:\\Users\\sromero\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI50802\\clidriver\\bin'
[18820] Failed to execute script 'TicketingIngenieria' due to unhandled exception!
```

And when I converted the file from .py to .exe I got this message in the CMD:

```
c:\py_project\ticketingingenieriavenv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
```

I have no idea what to do, I can guess is module related, but executing the script with Python does work, once I execute it as an executable it just gives me these errors. This is the list of modules:

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from pprint import pprint
import pyodbc
import ibm_db
import os
```

This is the command that I used:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "G:/09 SCRIPTS AUTOMATIZACION/tst/FLOS.ico;."  "G:/09 SCRIPTS AUTOMATIZACION/tst/TicketingIngenieria.py"
```

**EDIT:**
Included clidriver directory to the pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "G:/09 SCRIPTS AUTOMATIZACION/tst/FLOS.ico;." --add-data "C:/py_project/TicketingIngenieriaVENV/Lib/site-packages/clidriver;clidriver/"  "G:/09 SCRIPTS AUTOMATIZACION/tst/TicketingIngenieria.py"
```

And that gave the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: Could not find the specified module
```

**EDIT:**
Tried to add: `--add-data "C:/py_project/TicketingIngenieriaVENV/Lib/site-packages/clidriver/bin/amd64.VC12.CRT;./clidriver/"`

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] System cannot find the specified file: 'C:\\Users\\sromero\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI189962\\clidriver\\bin'
```

**SYSTEM VERSIONS:**

- Python version: 3.9.4
- Auto-py-to-exe: 2.9.0
- Operative System: Windows 10 Pro 21H1 (SO compilation 19043.1165)

Comment: Updated with the command that I used! But I do not understand the second sentence, I did not configure anything but the ODBC, do you mean that?

Comment: If you are planning to run the executable on a different hostname, you need to additionally include the clidriver directory, with the `--add-data` . See related answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63061992/ibm-db-pyinstaller-dll-issue

Comment: I have tried that, this is the command: `pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --add-data "G:/09 SCRIPTS AUTOMATIZACION/tst/FLOS.ico;." --add-data "C:/py_project/TicketingIngenieriaVENV/Lib/site-packages/clidriver;clidriver/"  "G:/09 SCRIPTS AUTOMATIZACION/tst/TicketingIngenieria.py"` and this is the new error: `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: Could not find the specified module`

Comment: Please edit your question to detail the Microsoft Windows version , the edition and build (from winver command), and also please try the additional parameter to pyinstaller: `--add-data "C:/py_project/TicketingIngenieriaVENV/Lib/site-packages/clidriver/bin/x86.VC12.CRT;./clidriver/" `

Comment: Question updated with the result.

Comment: Need to get the exact path correct, I think that the missing DLL is `msvcr120.dll` which is normally in the  `x86.VC12.CRT` directory. Some experimentation needed.

Comment: I do not have `x86.VC12.CRT` but I have `C:\py_project\TicketingIngenieriaVENV\Lib\site-packages\clidriver\bin\amd64.VC12.CRT`. And inside that directory I see `mscvr120.dll`, `mscvp120.dll` and `amd64.VC12.CRT.manifest`.

Comment: OK that is the correct directory for 64bit, so try specifying that directory with the `--add-data` and verify the files get copies to your image, you want them to be in a directory that will be added to the PATH when the built executable runs.

Comment: I put both directories, `clidriver` and `PATH` but i get the same DLL error from the question edit.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution, I had to add directly the ibm_db.dll to the script. This is the command that worked for me:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --add-data "G:/09 SCRIPTS AUTOMATIZACION/tst/FLOS.ico;." --add-binary "C:/py_project/TicketingIngenieriaVENV/Lib/site-packages/ibm_db_dlls/ibm_db.dll;ibm_db_dlls/" --add-data "C:/py_project/TicketingIngenieriaVENV/Lib/site-packages/clidriver;clidriver/" --paths "C:/py_project/TicketingIngenieriaVENV/Lib/site-packages/clidriver/bin/amd64.VC12.CRT"  "C:/py_project/TicketingIngenieriaVENV/TicketingIngenieria.py"
```